# In R: I want to check how many times one value of df1$A is in df2$A

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

```
df1 
A B
1 x
2 x
3 x
4 x
5 x
6 x
7 x

And df2
A 
1
1
1
2
2
1
5
```

Not I want to check how many times one value of df1$A is in df2$A.
The output should look like this:

```
1  4 (times)
2  2
3  0 
4  0
5  1
6  0
7  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have df1 and df2 we could do this in base R to solve this problem. To do this we'll have to iterate over each value in `df1$A`, and then match them to the values of `df2$A`. So this is quite the manual process, but there will be no way around this process.

```
# Find the unique values in df1$A. 
# In case we have the same value twice in df1, we don't want to match twice.
values_1 <- unique(df1$A)
# To merge the result we need the indices of our unique values in df1$A.
positions <- match(values_1, df1$A)
# Count the number of times the specific value is in df2
count <- sapply(values_1, function(x) sum(x == df2$A) )
# Add a new column to df1, using the positions for indexing.
df1$count <- count[positions]
```

This yields the expected result

```
df1
## Output ##
#   A count
# 1 1     4
# 2 2     2
# 3 3     0
# 4 4     0
# 5 5     1
# 6 6     0
# 7 7     0
```

## Edit: Alternative (faster) answer:

One alternative I thought of after giving the above solution is to "pre-tabularize" the data from `df2` and matching with `values_1`. This will be much faster for large datasets in the case where the values from `df1$A` are closely related to the values in `df2$A` in the sense that `df2$A` does not comprise of a large set of unique values (not unique count) that are not present in `df1$A`.

This idea is kinda similar, but changes the latter part of our code.

```
# Find the unique values in df1$A. 
# In case we have the same value twice in df1, we don't want to match twice.
values_1 <- unique(df1$A)
# To merge the result we need the indices of our unique values in df1$A.
positions <- match(values_1, df1$A)
# Count number of unique values in df2$A
count <- table(df2$A)
# match values_1 to the names of count, and insert these values into df1$count
df1$count <- count[match(values_1, names(count))][positions]
```

And this gives a similar result, however with `NA_integer_` in place of the values of `0`.

Note this second approach can be done even faster by using alternatives to the `table` function, which does not convert our values into factors, because factors are in general very slow.